# How do I get the custom attribute value of a field?

Tags: c#, attributes, filehelpers

I am using FileHelpers to write out fixed length files.

```
 public class MyFileLayout
{

    [FieldFixedLength(2)]
    private string prefix;

    [FieldFixedLength(12)]
    private string customerName;

    public string CustomerName
    {
        set 
        { 
            this.customerName= value;
            **Here I require to get the customerName's FieldFixedLength attribute value**

        }
    }
}
```

As shown above, I would like a access the custom attribute value inside the set method of the property.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: There's also this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320591/getting-values-from-custom-field-attributes-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using reflection.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class FieldFixedLengthAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [FieldFixedLength(Length = 2)]
    public string fileprefix { get; set; }

    [FieldFixedLength(Length = 12)]
    public string customerName { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var prop in typeof(Person).GetProperties())
        {
            var attrs = (FieldFixedLengthAttribute[])prop.GetCustomAttributes
                (typeof(FieldFixedLengthAttribute), false);
            foreach (var attr in attrs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, attr.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for more information please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925686/retrieve-custom-attribute-parameter-values)

Answer (score 4):

The only way of doing this is using the reflection:

```
var fieldInfo = typeof(MyFileLayout).GetField("customerName", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
var length = ((FieldFixedLengthAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fieldInfo, typeof(FieldFixedLengthAttribute))).Length;
```

I've tested it with following `FieldFixedLengthAttribute` implementation:

```
public class FieldFixedLengthAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Length { get; private set; }

    public FieldFixedLengthAttribute(int length)
    {
        Length = length;
    }
}
```

You have to adapt the code to reflect properties of your attribute class.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you. Almost over, but need a little fix.
 
var length =
                    ((FieldFixedLengthAttribute)
                     Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fieldInfo, typeof (FieldFixedLengthAttribute))).Length;


I am getting this error message: 'FileHelpers.FieldFixedLengthAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'Length'

Comment: @vijay Sure, I've created my own attribute class, with `Length` property. You have to adapt the code to reflect your attribute class structure.

Comment: Thank you, FieldFixedLengthAttribute is defined in the FileHelpers library. I am only using the dll. Removing the "Length" at the end is working: var length = ((FieldFixedLengthAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fieldInfo, typeof (FieldFixedLengthAttribute))); But on mouse over I could see FieldFixedLengthAttribute type is already exposing property named "Length", [this is the screenshot link](http://i.imgur.com/2rsyQfs.png). I looked into the FileHelpers lib source code and found that the "Length" property is declared as internal. Is there anyway to extract the value from it?